# Operation Flashpoint Laptop

Tags: identify-this-computer

In the 2001 video game, [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis), there is a laptop that appears in the menu:

[image: https://i.redd.it/on7mlfn53jlz.jpg]

What's the name of that laptop?
The game was released in 2001, and the story is set in 1985 during the Cold War.

Sorry, but I cant rip the model for now, so if the front view isn't enough, just tip me so I can rip the model/texture of that laptop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the Texas Instruments [TravelMate 4000e](http://www.computer-retro.de/Bilder/Laptops/SO-Texas-Instruments-TravelMate-4000E-486-WinSX-25MHz-Color-ohne-Netzteil.jpg) from 1993.

Comment: Looks like a perfect hit.