# Which computer is used in this NCIS episode?

Tags: identify-this-computer

My wife is a fan of NCIS and I just watched an episode of the Los Angeles version with her.  In it, the bad guys take over a nuclear launch control center.  They try to re-target the missiles.  They appear to be using Commodore 64s but we don't get a close-up.

Comment: As per [Is current use of retro technologies on-topic](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/278), this question is off-topic.

Comment: Could I rephrase it is identification?  Or does it just have to go?

Comment: If your question is "what is the computer in this frame / clip?"... I'll check.

Comment: Rephrased.  I hope that it is on topic now.

Comment: It's on-topic... but not really answerable. If you could make your question look more like [this one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5722/278) it would be much easier for people to answer it.

Comment: I don't have any easy way to get a screen capture.  I was hoping that someone else may have watched the episode

Comment: Ok. I'll make a couple of edits, but it probably won't get an answer for a while.

Comment: Would probably help if you identify which episode (by number or title), as different episodes air on different dates in different regions...

Comment: Thanks.  It is only curiosity so a late answer or no answer is not serious.

Comment: @Jules I may be able to do that.  I'll try an undelete on the DVR.

Comment: It's actually NCIS LA, Season 9, Episode 7. And I'm pretty sure it actually *is* a C64

Comment: Related, or even a duplicate: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82792/does-the-us-really-use-c64-computers-for-the-launch-control-of-their-missiles

Comment: @tofro Yes, that is it.

Comment: @tofro Post an answer?

Comment: Generally NCIS has a rather lenient attitude towards computer accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually NCIS LA, Season 9, Episode 7. And I'm pretty sure it actually is a C64

[This](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82792/does-the-us-really-use-c64-computers-for-the-launch-control-of-their-missiles) question on *Movies&TV* has some footage from the series and the computer definitely looks like a C64.

Comment: I was watching John Wick 2 the other day and I noticed that the computer used for logging assassination contracts [was very familiar](https://s9.postimg.org/9j2ufj3hb/Screenshot_2017-04-05-18-55-31.png).

Comment: @JeremyP the link seems to be dead.